# What this line means in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm now reading Swift 3 book and found this line there:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {

}
```

and there are just this description:

```
Functions can also take a variable number of arguments, collecting them into an array.
```

I did not get what that `(numbers: Int...)` means. Can anyone explain me, please?

Comment: Somebody never used `printf()` :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called `variadic arguments`, explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.
>   You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be
>   passed a varying number of input values when the function is called.
>   Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (...)
>   after the parameter’s type name.

Comment: so, it's like an array, yes?

Comment: I don't know about Swift specifically, but in other languages the values are separated by commas (,) so they are separate elements, not an array.

Comment: @Doe No, it means that you can pass one or more arguments of that type, but it does not specify how many (like a normal function declaration). On the called side, yes, it is treated as an array. But on the calling side, instead of passing an array, you pass individual values separated by commas. **How many, is up to you.**

Answer (score 2):

As per the above explanation the variadic arguments are variable number of argument the function takes variable number of arguments in a numbers array. so if you want to print each element you can do so by

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum:Int = 0

    for num in numbers {
        sum = sum + num
    }
    return sum
}
```

and the number of int element passed to this number may very.

Answer (score 0):

Example for using function with varidic arguments

```
func log(args: AnyObject ...) {
  var text = ""
  for arg in args {
    text += " \(arg)"
  }
  print("\(text)")
}
```

log("Arg1", "Arg2")

log("Arg1", "Arg2", "Arg3")